# GoogleApiAvailability: Unexpected error code 19

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

Recently while implementing [SMS-API according to google doc](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) faced issue when SMS receiver was not working giving me the following error:

> GoogleApiAvailability: Unexpected error code 19

There is no information about this error neither in official documentation nor in google search.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was permissions of Google Play Services, particularly its about SMS permission which was denied. That was the reason of Unexpected error code 19, after granting this permission to Google Play Services everything woks just fine.
The main profit of this (API) approach is not asking for SMS access in your app. It is OK when users are denying such permission cuz it gives app possibility to read absolutely any user SMS for sake of handling only 1 special SMS. Thats why Google make this API for us, but while your app will not ask for SMS permission Google Services will need it definitely.